# Do pm2 restart terminate ongoing rest api's

Tags: node.js, pm2

i am using pm2 in production apps

will pm2 restart terminate ongoing rest api's?

If yes then Is there a workaround for not terminating the existing Rest API's when pm2 restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use cluster mode (`-i 4`) and [`pm2 reload`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#reload) to do zero downtime deploys.

There's a guide that goes in depth over things over here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-cluster-mode-and-zero-downtime-restarts

Comment: I am having one more query, i am not using http module instead directly using app.listen() for starting the application. Do pm2 cluser work with this example